# Electron write file when packaged

Tags: electron, electron-packager

**In electron, how can I write a file when the app *is packaged* using electron packager.**

The following will create and update the file in development. But once I package the app using electron-packager, the file will no longer be created. What do I need to change?

```js
// imports
const path = require('path');
const fs = require('fs');

// create stream for appending to the log file
stream = fs.createWriteStream(
    path.join(__dirname, 'logfile.log'),
    {
        flags:'a'
    }
);

// append content to the log file
stream.write('test');
```

Here's how I package it:

```
  "scripts": {
    "start": "electron .",
    "pack:win64": "electron-packager . my-app --out=dist/win64 --platform=win32 --arch=x64 --icon=assets/icon.png --prune=true --overwrite --asar"
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried this but perhaps you could use the [afterCopy](https://github.com/electron/electron-packager/blob/master/docs/api.md) hook to call the function you need?

> **afterCopy**
>
> Array of Functions
>
> An array of functions to be called after your app directory has been
>   copied to a temporary directory. Each function is called with five
>   parameters:
>
> ```
> buildPath (String): The path to the temporary folder where your app has been copied to
> electronVersion (String): The version of electron you are packaging for
> platform (String): The target platform you are packaging for
> arch (String): The target architecture you are packaging for
> callback (Function): Must be called once you have completed your actions
> ```

---

```
const packager = require('electron-packager')
const { serialHooks } = require('electron-packager/hooks')

packager({
  // ...
  afterCopy: [serialHooks([
    (buildPath, electronVersion, platform, arch) => {
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        setTimeout(() => {
          console.log('first function')
          resolve()
        }, 1000)
      })
    },
    (buildPath, electronVersion, platform, arch) => {
      console.log('second function')
    }
  ])],
  // ...
})
```

Comment: Thanks. Turns out, if I remove ` --asar` from the packaging process, the file is there.